# why char like "$" "\" are not bash shell metacharacter

Tags: bash, shell

While reading the Bash Reference Manual I noticed in the [Definitions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html):

> *metacharacter*
>
> A character that, when unquoted, separates words. A metacharacter is a space, tab, newline, or one of the following characters: ‘|’, ‘&’, ‘;’, ‘(’, ‘)’, ‘<’, or ‘>’.

but chars like $, \ and others have all a special meaning. Why aren't they  listed as metacharacters?

Answer (score 2):

You posted the answer in the question (as part of the text you quoted from the documentation).

A **metacharacter** is:

> A character that, when unquoted, separates words.

Neither `$`, nor `\` are used to separate words. When not quoted, both of them are kept together with the character(s) that follow(s) them.

`$` is the [sigil of a variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)).
`\` is used as [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Comment: Ok, but metacharacter should be something having specially meaning, more than just for separating words. I do not understand why they think only char separators are metacharacter

Comment: and here : https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/courses/782/unix/node21.html  
 
seems to be more accurate.

Comment: You quoted from a file named "Definitions". This is how `bash` defines the word **metacharacter** for the rest of its documentation.

Comment: Ok, so when we are talking about shell metacharacter, we are not talking about the definition gnu used here, right ?

Comment: @caesarwang That page is not authoritative in any way. It's making up its own definition of metacharacter that has nothing to do with the bash documentation.

Comment: @chepner but it is actually the bash manual as you can see in the url

Comment: @caesarwang No, the link you provided to stat.auckland.ac.nz is most decidedly *not* the bash manual. The link in your question *is*, however, from the bash manual and provides the only definition of "metacharacter" that is relevant to the rest of the manual, your personal feelings aside.